# check the if DOM has class name attached to it

Tags: jquery

I want to check if a Dom has class value attached to it.. Since that DOM will be assigned a random class value dynamically, I will not know the class name specifically, so is it possible to check if it has a class element attached to irrespective of its class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($('div').attr('class')!= "") { //class is there and its not empty }
```

Answer (score 6):

That?

```
if($('div').prop('class').length) { }
```

Related docs:

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

This basically pulls out the `class` property from `div` (change that to your actualy DOM element you'd like to check for class existence) and check whether it has `length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Class in markup is an attribute so can use:

```
   var className=  $(selector).attr('class');
  if( className ){
      /* do Something*/
  }
```

[attr() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)